# Project Build gets Skipped in VS2008 after conversion from VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I recently installed VS2008 and opened a VS2005 project(C++). Then after the conversion to VS2008, i tried building the project. But the project is getting skipped. I tried Clean as well as Rebuild, and it is getting skipped for those as well.

How can i solve this problem and build the project in VS 2008?

Forgot to mention, Also in Build->Configuration Manager, Build option is ticked.

Comment: What is the Platform set to in Project Properties->Build?

Comment: This is the exact same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176200/visual-studio-2008-skipping-projects-when-building-a-solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

Though build check box is selected in Build->Configuration Manager, i was not able to build and the project got skipped when i tried to Build, Rebuild or Clean the solution.

As i was using Win2k8 R2 machine(64bit) i had to install VS 64bit compiler which wont be installed by default. So i had to install the feature again using Add/Remove features in VS2008 and the problem got solved.

I found this as I was able to build it for 32 bit but not for 64 bit.

Comment: How to install that 64-bit feature is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979675/visual-studio-2008-c-no-x64-platform

Answer (score 0):

Go in the Configuration Manager and ensure the build checkbox for that project is set.

Right-click the Solution node in the Solution Explorer Window and choose 'Configuration Manager...'.

Answer (score 0):

as most all of the other answers have mentioned the `Configuration Manager...` has checkboxes to control the building of projects.

right clicking solution explorer gets you to `configuration manager...`, but so does the `Build` menu. `Build->Configuration Manager`

If it is still skipping make sure you are not mixing incompatible versions of .net framework frameworks together between components.  Check out the `Active Solution Platform` drop down in the Configration manager; prune the solution platforms of those which do not apply. ie. `Mixed Platforms` and `x86` which sometimes get randomly added during conversion.

Answer (score -1):

In your `Build->Configuration Manager`, make sure that the Project's `Build` option is ticked.

Comment: ya it is set but still the prob persists.