# Visual Studio 2008 skipping projects when building a solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I recently installed VS2008 in Win2k8R2 machine and opened a VS2005 project(C++). After successful conversion to VS2008, I tried building the project in Debug x64 mode. But the project is getting skipped. I tried Clean as well as Rebuild, and it is getting skipped for those as well.

I'm able to build in Debug win32 mode. But I need to build in x64 mode.

Also the Build option is ticked in Build->Configuration Manager under x64.

I have installed the x64 bit compiler too.

Also I'm not able to see the Project properties for x64.

How can I solve this problem and build the project in VS 2008?

Comment: It is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091362/project-build-gets-skipped-in-vs2008-after-conversion-from-vs2005 , as even after trying those, the problem persists.

Comment: Did you create project configurations for x64?

Comment: No. It was already available. But i'm not able to build in x64.??

Answer (score 0):

Open your solution and project files in a text editor; make sure they have the correct path to your 2008 project folders. I've noticed conversions that don't fix the path for you; the mix up is that your UI may be pointing to the correct location (say, your solution is fine), but it's actually targeting your old 2005 projects.