# Visual Studio 2008 skipping projects when building a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I recently installed VS2008 in Win2k8R2 machine and opened a VS2005 project(C++). After successful conversion to VS2008, i tried building the project in Debug x64 mode. But the project is getting skipped. I tried Clean as well as Rebuild, and it is getting skipped for those as well.

I'm able to build in Debug win32 mode. But i need to build in x64 mode.

Also the Build option is ticked in Build->Configuration Manager under x64.

I have installed the x64 bit compiler too.

How can i solve this problem and build the project in VS 2008?

Comment: Do you even have a x64 machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option to only build the currently active project and its dependencies, a project not in the dependency graph will be skipped even if it needs a build.

Check Tools | Options | Projects And Solutions | Build and Run | Only Build Startup projects and dependencies on Run.

You can also see the inter-project dependencies and net build order in Project | Project Build Order (assuming with is available for C++ projects --- don't have one to hand to check).

Comment: +1 to you kind sir, even though I don't have this problem this is a nice thing to know about Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is C++ you could try building it from the prompt with cl.exe .

Comment: even when i try  from command prompt, the project is getting skipped