# Errors while building/installing C module for Python 2.7

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying getting the following errors while trying to install/compile [ctools](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/default/tutorials/speedup.html#using-the-c-version-of-the-nsga-ii-algorithm) for python (version info)

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:22:14) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

- OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (Service Pack 1)
- Installed: Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition

Error:

```
building 'deap.cTools' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    cmdclass = {'build_py': build_py}
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 499, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

I've installed PyWin as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676728/value-error-trying-to-install-python-for-windows-extensions), but it didn't help. I'd appreciate help sorting out this issue.

**Edit**

Same issue arises when trying to install `scikit-learn`

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: @kuyan: (1) I've already installed Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 without setting the variables (2) I can't find setenv on my machine (3) My promot isn't yellow.

Comment: ... Note that I trying to build a module and not python.

Answer (score 21):

I summarized above in my blog. 
http://springflex.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-fix-valueerror-when-trying-to.html

To install Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition with all required components:

1. Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition. The main Visual Studio 2008 Express installer is available from (the C++ installer name is vcsetup.exe):
2. Install the Microsoft Windows SDK. The Microsoft Windows SDK is available by searching Microsoft's download site, or by going directly to:
   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en
3. To verify that you have all installed components, check that the Microsoft SDK contains the "amd64" version of the C/C++ compiler "cl.exe". This is usually installed into

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe
   ```
4. copy .../VC/bin/vcvars64.bat to .../VC/bin/vcvarsamd64.bat
5. copy .../VC/bin/vcvars64.bat to .../VC/bin/amd64/vcvarsamd64.bat

Comment: I've had this problem a long time now, and this is the only thing that I've found that's worked!

Comment: Is the solution for a 32 bit system analogous?

Answer (score 18):

Since you're using the 64 bit version of Python, once you have installed [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138)  (which installs the 64bit compiler that isn't installed when installing [Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Express Edition](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/5/4/A54BADB6-9C3F-478D-8657-93B3FC9FE62D/vcsetup.exe)); You need to copy the `vcvars64.bat` to a location where `vcvarsall.bat` *claims* it to be.

From `%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\`, you need to [copy](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/460547/visual-studio-express-2008-and-64-bit-compiles-on-win7-how-to-fix-visual-studio-express-64-bit-compi/) `vcvars64.bat` to `amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat`.

Note the **amd** part in the destination file name.

Comment: the solution is actually the same as provided below by user2276550 but instead of using Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, he uses Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5. The problem is that your solution doesn't work unless I do "copy .../VC/bin/vcvars64.bat to .../VC/bin/vcvarsamd64.bat" as illustrated the 4th step of user2276550's post. Is that a missing step?

Comment: If anyone is worried about trying to find a newer .NET framework SDK, don't worry.  I already had 4.6.1 installed but I went ahead and installed 3.5 as instructed here, copied the files, and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft now publishes a [Visual C++ compiler just for Python 2.7](http://aka.ms/vcpython27), although it will work for other versions of Python that used the same compiler. Check the system requirements: setuptools 6.0 or later is required. It will not work with packages using distutils.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue because I did not have the 64-bit version of Visual C++ 2008.  To solve the issue, I installed it through Change/Remove in Programs and Features, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981596/1397061).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but just renaming the files listed above (in a somewhat opaque way) didn't work for me.  What did work is a much easier solution.  Just run vcvarsall.bat before you start the install. This sets the correct paths and is much easier to understand. In my case, I needed a 64 bit build so I ran:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64