# why Installing external package in canopy python gives valueEror in windows?

Tags: python, windows, installation, package, canopy

This question has been asked a couple of times and I spend at least five hours trying to incorporate suggestions in those posts [but was mostly unsuccessful.

I installed Canopy Enthought python on my windows and now I want to install Levenshtein package available at https://code.google.com/p/pylevenshtein/.

I extracted and tried to run using usual python command but got the following error.

```
(Canopy 64bit) C:\Users\mary\Desktop>cd python-Levenshtein-0.11.2

(Canopy 64bit) C:\Users\mary\Desktop\python-Levenshtein-0.11.2>python setup.
py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\requires.txt
writing python_Levenshtein.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing namespace_packages to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt

writing top-level names to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribu
tion
warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in dist
ribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in
 distribution
writing manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'Levenshtein' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 46, in <module>
    """,
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\
setuptools\command\install.py", line 73, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\
setuptools\command\install.py", line 93, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\
setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 179, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\
setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 166, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\
setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 20, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\
setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 46, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 446, in build_extens
ions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\
setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 182, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self,ext)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_extens
ion
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 514, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 424, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Users\mary\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.
0.1938.win-x86_64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 340, in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']

(Canopy 64bit) C:\Users\mary\Desktop\python-Levenshtein-0.11.2>
```

I followed these posts but remained unsuccessful in solving this issue:
[Errors while building/installing C module for Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596407/errors-while-building-installing-c-module-for-python-2-7)
http://springflex.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-fix-valueerror-when-trying-to.html

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error, badly handled by Python 2.7's distutils. The underlying meaning is "You must have Visual C++ 2008 installed to do this build". Other than that, I suggest installing Gohlke's build: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein

Comment: before doing so, be sure that Canopy User Python is your default Python, as described in https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python (be sure to read Note 3).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I tried to install and uninstall a couple of times but  was unsuccessful. Your solution was quite handy and worked perfectly.