# pycrypto installation: configure error: cannot run C compiled programs

Tags: python, paramiko, mingw32, pycrypto

Please be gentle on me.  I have searched the site, and I know there is another answer to this exact question, but the answers posted there aren't working for me.

I am trying to install `pycrypto`, so that I can get `paramiko` to work.  `Paramiko` is failing because of a missing `pycrypto` module.  I have tried using `pip install pycrypto` which succeeds, but does not cure the problem.

I have tried installing a binary version of `pycrypto` and that doesn't solve the problem.

Now I am trying to build `pycrypto`.  I have `cygwin64` and `mingw` installed on my machine.  The approach that gets the farthest is

```
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

This gets to an error,

```
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/Python27/pycrypto-2.6.1':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
```

The other answer suggests removing spaces in the path.  I have tried reducing the path to simply

```
c:\mingw;c:\python2.7;c:\cygwin64\bin
```

with no change to the result?

Does anyone have a fix they can point me to?  Thank you.  The overall goal is to get `paramiko` to work.  The `paramiko` error is

```
ImportError: No module named Crypto.PublicKey
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the `/tmp` mount point was mounted with the `noexec` flag.

For windows with cygwin, I would check the mount point too, as well as dependencies such as the `vcredist` packages required for python2 and python3, see also [Errors while building/installing C module for Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596407/errors-while-building-installing-c-module-for-python-2-7/19915585#19915585).

Two solutions for linux:

- remount temporarily with the exec flag (very likely requires root/sudo permissions)

e.g.:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,exec /tmp
```

- change the build path to a local mount point

e.g.:

```
mkdir -p ~/python/tmp
pip install --build ~/python/tmp pycrypto
```

Note: it's worth looking at the other answers:

- verify `autoconf` and `python2-dev` or `python3-dev` packages are installed.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem:

```
pip install --upgrade subprocess32
```

failed with

```
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs
```

on `aws` after our admins tightened the settings and mounted `tmpfs` with the `noexec` option.

The solution was

```
TMPDIR=/var/tmp pip install --upgrade subprocess32
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message when installing pycrypto (although nothing to do with paramiko). The solution for me was:

```
yum install autoconf
TMPDIR=/home/$USER/tmp
TMP=$TMPDIR
TEMP=$TMPDIR
export TMPDIR TMP TEMP
```

and then install again:

```
pip install pocrypto
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in Chrubuntu 14.04, and solved it by first doing:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

...to fix something to do with header files, and then:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

...to solve the actual problem with paramiko.  However, then paramiko had a problem with something ecdsa, and 'pip install paramiko' said everything was already installed, no problem, so I did 'pip uninstall paramiko' followed by 'pip install paramiko', and now I can import paramiko in python without a problem.

There is probably a more elegant way to solve that last bit but this worked well enough for me.