# v8.5 - Error Compiling Parallel Transformer

Tags: c++, transformer-model, datastage

I would appreciate if i can get some help in solving this issue for which i have been looking for information for over 2 days through various forums.  Crying or Very sad  Crying or Very sad

I have installed Infosphere Datastage v8.5 on windows environment for testing and have run a couple of jobs, but when i run a job containing a transformer i get compilation error.

Job: Row generator -> Tfx -> Sequential File

Based on my search through various forums i find that Similar issue has been faced by others as well.But i am unable to find a concrete answer regarding the following: 
1. A Compiler that i need to install and the related SDK that needs to be installed along with it 
2. or A combined pack that has both compiler+SDK

The Installation Guide talks about Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2008 Express Edition C++: but does not mention which is the associated SDK that needs to be installed ? 
or is there a newer version of C++ compiler+SDK that will work on my environment

## My Environment Details:

OS  -   Windows Server 2008 R2(Standard) SP1 - 64 bit

IIS -   Infosphere Information Server v8.5 64bit Multilingual

--================

.Net framework

--================

Microsoft .Net framework 1.1

Microsoft .Net framework 4 Client Profile

Microsoft .Net framework 4 Extended

--=====

SDK

--=====

Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

This SDK created 2 directories path , which are as follows:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0

## Windows Environment Variables:

INCLUDE - C:\IBM\SQLLIB\INCLUDE;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include

LIB - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB

CLASSPATH   - .;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\java\sqlj.zip; 
C:\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\bin;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\java\common.jar

Path    - C:\IBM\InformationServer\Server\DSComponents\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin64;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin; 
C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\bin\X11;C:\PROGRA~2\MKSTOO~1\mksnt;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\jre\bin\classic;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\lib\cpp; 
C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cpp\vc60\MT_dll\bin;%systemroot%\system32;%systemroot%; 
%systemroot%\system32\wbem;%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\bin; 
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\common7\ide;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION; 
C:\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\Windows/SysWOW64

## Compiler information from windows command prompt:

c:\Users\skh>cl.exe

Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

## Datastage Environment Variables:

APT_COMPILEOPT (old):   -W/TP -W/EHa -DAPT_USE_ANSI_IOSTREAMS -c -W/Zc:wchar_t- 
APT_COMPILEOPT (new):   -W/TP -W/EHa -DAPT_USE_ANSI_IOSTREAMS -c

APT_LINKOPT(old):   -s -W/dll -W/base:0x50000000 -W/Zc:wchar_t-

APT_LINKOPT(new):   -s -W/dll -W/base:0x50000000

The (old) represent the default values that DS Environment variables had. I ran my job which had a transformer but i got the compilation error. 
I changed the Environment variable values to what is stated in (new), still i get the compilation error mentioned below

---

Output from transformer compilation follows:

### I IIS-DSEE-TFCN-00001 12:55:36(000)

IBM WebSphere DataStage Enterprise Edition 8.5.0.5746 
Copyright (c) 2001, 2005-2008 IBM Corporation. All rights reserved

```
##I IIS-DSEE-TFCN-00006 12:55:36(001) <main_program> conductor uname: -s=Windows_NT; -r=1; -v=6; -n=IN-MUM-IBMQLT; -m=Pentium 
##I IIS-DSEE-TOSH-00002 12:55:36(002) <main_program> orchgeneral: loaded 
##I IIS-DSEE-TOSH-00002 12:55:36(003) <main_program> orchsort: loaded 
##I IIS-DSEE-TOSH-00002 12:55:36(004) <main_program> orchstats: loaded 
##W IIS-DSEE-TOSH-00049 12:55:36(007) <main_program> Parameter specified but not used in flow: DSPXWorkingDir 
##E IIS-DSEE-TBLD-00076 12:55:39(000) <main_program> Error when checking composite operator: Subprocess command failed with exit status 256. 
##E IIS-DSEE-TFSR-00019 12:55:39(001) <main_program> Could not check all operators because of previous error(s) 
##W IIS-DSEE-TFTM-00012 12:55:39(002) <transform> Error when checking composite operator: The number of reject datasets "0" is less than the number of input datasets "1". 
##I IIS-DSEE-TBLD-00000 12:55:39(003) <main_program> Error when checking composite operator: Output from subprocess: cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'GX' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release 
cl : Command line warning D9036 : use 'EHsc' instead of 'GX' 
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/GX' with '/EHa' 

##I IIS-DSEE-TBLD-00000 12:55:39(004) <main_program> Error when checking composite operator: Output from subprocess: C:\IBM\InformationServer\Server\PXEngine\include\apt_util/ints.h(83) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'strstream': No such file or directory 

##W IIS-DSEE-TFEV-00025 12:55:39(005) <transform> Error when checking composite operator: Converting string to number. 
##W IIS-DSEE-TFEV-00023 12:55:39(006) <transform> Error when checking composite operator: Implicit conversion from source type "String" to result type "DFloat". 
##W IIS-DSEE-TFEV-00025 12:55:39(007) <transform> Error when checking composite operator: Converting number to string. 
##W IIS-DSEE-TFEV-00023 12:55:39(008) <transform> Error when checking composite operator: Implicit conversion from source type "DFloat" to result type "String". 
##W IIS-DSEE-TBLD-00000 12:55:39(009) <main_program> Error when checking composite operator: Output from subprocess: ld: script execution error in file 'C:/PROGRA~2/MKSTOO~1/etc/nutccg/ld.ccg' on line 1119 
>>> execv: could not run 'link32': The system cannot find the file specified. 

##I IIS-DSEE-TBLD-00079 12:55:39(010) <transform> Error when checking composite operator: cxx -LC:/IBM/InformationServer/Server/Projects/PRJ_QSPOC/RT_BP2.O/ -LC:/IBM/InformationServer/Server/PXEngine/lib -LC:/IBM/InformationServer/Server/PXEngine/user_lib -s -W/dll -W/base:0x50000000 -lliborchnt -lliborchcorent -lliborchbuildopnt C:/IBM/InformationServer/Server/Projects/PRJ_QSPOC/RT_BP2.O/V0S3_TestJob_Tfx_Transformer.tmp.o -o C:/IBM/InformationServer/Server/Projects/PRJ_QSPOC/RT_BP2.O/V0S3_TestJob_Tfx_Transformer.dll. 
##E IIS-DSEE-TCOS-00029 12:55:39(011) <main_program> Creation of a step finished with status = FAILED. (TestJob_Tfx.Transformer) 

*** Internal Generated Transformer Code follows: 
0001: // 
0002: // Generated file to implement the V0S3_TestJob_Tfx_Transformer transform operator. 
0003: // 
0004: 
0005: // define our input/output link names 
0006: inputname 0 DSLink2; 
0007: outputname 0 DSLink5; 
0008: 
0009: initialize { 
0010: // define our control variables 
0011: int8 RowRejected0; 
0012: int8 NullSetVar0; 
0013: 
0014: } 
0015: 
0016: mainloop { 
0017: 
0018: // declare our intermediate variables for this section 
0019: dfloat InterVar0_0; 
0020: 
0021: // initialise the rejected row variable 
0022: RowRejected0 = 1; 
0023: 
0024: // evaluate columns (no constraints) for link: DSLink5 
0025: InterVar0_0 = DSLink2.Dummy1; 
0026: DSLink5.Dummy1 = (InterVar0_0 + 5); 
0027: writerecord 0; 
0028: RowRejected0 = 0; 
0029: } 
0030: 
0031: finish { 
0032: } 
0033: 
*** End of Internal Generated Transformer Code
```

Comment: @sepp2k have u come across this problem before ? did you have to uninstall the compiler and infosphere information server and then install a different version of compiler + infosphere information server ?Any information would be helpfull..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i went about fixing it. I hope this helps people facing similar problems and saves some time and effort.

so , here it goes :

I installed Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express Edition.

I then worked around vcvarsall.bat  file .if you are wondering why , please check

( 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s(v=vs.80).aspx )

and

[Errors while building/installing C module for Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596407/errors-while-building-installing-c-module-for-python-2-7)

)

I executed the following from the cmd window, to set the 64 bit compiler:

> vcvarsall.bat amd64

NOTE: my environment has a X64 AMD chipset windows server;I used echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% , from cmd window to determine this.

To cross check which compiler is set, execute the following and the output would indicate.

> cl.exe

Next , set the following windows system variables:

INCLUDE - C:\IBM\SQLLIB\INCLUDE;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB; C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include

LIB - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib ;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\LIB

Note:- 
The folder path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A is created by the Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express Edition. This should be the source for folder paths that are set for INCLUDE & LIB

There is a similar path that the SDK creates C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\ , but Include and Lib folder from this path should not be used to set the above mentioned Windows Environment variables , I made this mistake during my set up :(

for reference please check the Release Note of the SDK that is to be installed.

Set the following Datastage ENV variable,from the Administrator, to values below.

APT_COMPILEOPT :    -W/TP -W/EHa -DAPT_USE_ANSI_IOSTREAMS -c -W/Zc:wchar_t- 
APT_LINKOPT :   -s -W/dll -W/base:0x50000000 -W/Zc:wchar_t-

I then restarted the Datastage services.

.. and the transformers started to work :)

PS : I did not uninstall Information Server nor the SDK (which i initially presumed was the problem)