# Cannot compile python packages using C. Error 2 - Cannot open include file: 'alloca.h'?

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, pip

It all started with "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" But I fixed it pretty quickly. After that I cannot fix some "error 2".

Already tried instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596407/errors-while-building-installing-c-module-for-python-2-7/21898585#21898585):

- Installed Visual C++ compiler Python 2.7
- Installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition SP1
- Installed Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
- manipulated vcvarsall.bat and vsvars64

But still cannot install pyethash, PyYAML, scrypt. Details for pyethash are below.

Tried to install Crypto, which uses C++ libraries as well - and it works. Does it still looks like I have problems with compilers or should I look somewhere else?

Using windows 8.1 x64, python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

## Installing with pip

```
PS C:\pyethereum\ethash-master> pip install pyethash
Collecting pyethash
  Using cached pyethash-0.1.27.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyethash
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyethash ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\b19a~1\\ap
pdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-y2vsbx\\pyethash\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\b19a~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpwmonvkpip-wheel- --pytho
n-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pyethash' extension
  error: [Error 2]

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyethash
  Running setup.py clean for pyethash
Failed to build pyethash
Installing collected packages: pyethash
  Running setup.py install for pyethash ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\b19a~1\\
appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-y2vsbx\\pyethash\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\b19a~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-pvhu8d-record\insta
ll-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyethash' extension
    error: [Error 2]

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\b19a~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pi
p-build-y2vsbx\\pyethash\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
 __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\b19a~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-pvhu8d-record\install-record.txt --single-v
ersion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\b19a~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y2vsbx\pyethash\
```

## Installing manually

```
PS C:\pyethereum\ethash-master> python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyethash' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcsrc/python/core.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/python/core.obj -Isrc/ -std=gnu99 -Wallcl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'core.c
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(81) : warning C4820: 'PreAttribute' : '4' bytes padding added after data member 'Access'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(96) : warning C4820: 

....
....
c:\python27\include\import.h(61) : warning C4820: '_frozen' : '4' bytes padding added after data member 'size'
c:\python27\include\code.h(26) : warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>' : '4' bytes padding added after data member 'co_firstlineno'src/python/core.c(2) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'alloca.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 1):

alloca is only seen in Linux
it's a critical bug
see https://github.com/ethereum/ethash/pull/107

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the [essential parts of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.